# Collect all rows from different tables with true/false value depending on tables they came from

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have these different tables:

```
Participants_1
name   | age
James  | 18

Participants_2
name   | age
Daniel | 20
James  | 18
```

How can I insert it to another table like this?

```
All_Participants
name   | age | in_participants_1 | in_participants_2
James  | 18  | 1                 | 1
Daniel | 20  | 0                 | 1
```

So basically the **All_Participants** tables is the collection of all rows from other Participants tables with additional fields of `is_participants_*` if they came from specific tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `UNION ALL` with `GROUP BY`:

```sql
-- INSERT INTO ...
SELECT name, age, MAX(in_participants_1), MAX(in_participants_2)
FROM (
  SELECT name, age, 1 AS in_participants_1, 0 AS in_participants_2 FROM participants_1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT name, age, 0,                      1                      FROM participants_2
) AS u
GROUP BY name, age
```

Ideally you would store all participants in one table and store their ids in participants 1 and 2 table. Or better, create one participation table that stores participant id and event id.

Comment: You don't need MAX and GROUP BY??

Comment: If e.g. James is present in both tables you **do** need a group by.